# has_one of something it belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have User and Todo models

The Todo belongs_to User and User has_many todos

The todos can be marked as "done" and I want to store which user who marked it done.

I have this migration

```
class CreateTodos < ActiveRecord::Migration
def self.up
    create_table :todos do |t|
      t.integer :done_by_user
    end
  end
end
```

Now I want to store the user id of the user that marked the todo done in :done_by_user

I have tried this in the Todo class

```
has_one :done_by_user, :class_name => "User"
```

and this

```
has_one :done_by_user, :through => :user
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Todo class:

```
belongs_to :done_by_user, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "done_by_user"
```

In your User class

```
has_many :done_todos, :class_name => "Todo", :foreign_key => "done_by_user"
```

Now you can do this:

```
user.done_todos   => ['done_todo_1', 'done_todo_2', ... , 'done_todo_n']
todo.done_by_user => < User Object >
```

Comment: I get this `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.done_by_user: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."done_by_user" = 1 LIMIT 1`

Comment: Well. I'd really want to be able to call todo.done_by_user not todo.done_by_user.first. And I quess I'll have to add has_many :todos_done in the User class